# How to ORDER BY the amount of a given character in a string using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The column `OTI` in `traits_general` comprises of string values.  What I am attempting to do here is to select, in descending order by the amount of zeros in each string, each `OTI` value.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM traits_general
ORDER BY traits_general.OTI.amountOfZerosInString() DESC;
```

In this instance, if we had the strings, 03001, 22321, 00002, 30203, and 11102, then I would want for it to be ordered like such: 00002, 03001, 30203, 11102, 22321.

Is this possible to achieve?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to count the number of characters in a string is to replace the zeros with an empty string and compare the length of the original string and the one without the zeros:

```
order by length(oti) - length(replace(oti, '0', '')) desc
```

Comment: Even better, just remove the operation and only use `ORDER BY length(replace(OTI, '0', '')) ASC` instead.  Thank you, it worked!